# Returns java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in ProcessBuilder.start()

Tags: java, processbuilder

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandInformation);
Process process = pb.start();
```

Above code is returning error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:69)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    at com.ConvertsImages.SystemCommandExecutor.executeCommand(SystemCommandExecutor.java:51)
    at com.ConvertsImages.ImageConversion.runConvertCommand(ImageConversion.java:115)
    at com.ConvertsImages.ImageConversion.runConvert(ImageConversion.java:80)
    at com.ConvertsImages.ImageConversion.main(ImageConversion.java:26)
```

List **commandInformation** has only one entry as below:

```
["D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\convert.exe"  "D:\ConvertFiles\ReImport_2507_1.jpg"  -resize 40x40 "D:\ConvertFiles\proxy-40\ReImport_2507_1.jpg.jpg" ]
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `ProcessBuilder`, there is a method `isQuoted` that checks if a String argument is quoted and throws `IllegalArgumentException` if it is and a flag is checked.

```
private static boolean isQuoted(boolean noQuotesInside, String arg,
        String errorMessage) {
    int lastPos = arg.length() - 1;
    if (lastPos >=1 && arg.charAt(0) == '"' && arg.charAt(lastPos) == '"') {
        // The argument has already been quoted.
        if (noQuotesInside) {
            if (arg.indexOf('"', 1) != lastPos) {
                // There is ["] inside.
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    if (noQuotesInside) {
        if (arg.indexOf('"') >= 0) {
            // There is ["] inside.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The above is called from `getExecutablePath`, note the `true` flag

```
 boolean pathIsQuoted = isQuoted(true, path,
            "Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments");
```

which is called inside the `ProcessImpl` constructor

```
String executablePath = getExecutablePath(cmd[0]);
```

where `cmd` is the array created from your list. Index 0 matches the executable (in your case the whole String). In the String you showed us, your executable is quoted (or at least starts with one), so the method will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

This is confirmed by your stack trace

```
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:69)
```

That means inside your constructor.

Split each argument in your command list as a separate String element in the list. Don't put quotes around the executable.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need a list of 'n' arguments.

It's currently interpreting your first list entry as the executable, and that's clearly not right since it incorporates your arguments too.

Comment: Would that throw IllegalArgumentException or command not found?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, that the parameter passed in ProcessBuilder, `commandInformation is a String array or a List<String>.`

> Parameters: command A string array containing the program and its
>   arguments

```
Parameters:
command The list containing the program and its arguments
```

[Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.java#ProcessBuilder)

[Oracle Docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) which states one of the reasons for IllegalArgumetnException.

Also I just noticed the file name that you have is included with `.jpg.jpg` .
Shouldn't it be `fileName.jpg`

Comment: That's still doesn't answer the question. The OP stated _List commandInformation_, with the list's `toString()` being `["D:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\convert.exe"  "D:\ConvertFiles\ReImport_2507_1.jpg"  -resize 40x40 "D:\ConvertFiles\proxy-40\ReImport_2507_1.jpg.jpg" ]`.

Comment: I'm sorry but how is `java.awt.Desktop#open()` relevant? The `ProcessBuilder` uses a native method to create a process `using the win32 function CreateProcess`.

Comment: That was a wrong link, updated it. Also do you think the filename that the OP has is correct? It has filename.jpg.jpg?   "D:\ConvertFiles\proxy-40\ReImport_2507_1.jpg.jpg

Comment: Regardless of the filename and its existence, the `ProcessBuilder#start()` method would no throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for that reason. The underlying process would just fail with its own error message. Go through the source code, it's because of the starting `"` in his command. Check my answer.

Comment: Ok. True. From where did you find that method? I am trying to find it in Oracle docs, but cannot find it.

Comment: Oh, I have it in Eclipse. If you go to your java JDK installation, there is a `src.zip` containing the source code.